# What's the drag coefficient?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, integration

> Suppose an objects starts with velocity $v$. A damping force that is dependent of velocity acts on this object ($F=-\beta v$). After traversing distance $l$, the object has velocity $\alpha v$ with $0<\alpha<1$. Calculate the drag coefficient $\beta$.

Well, it seems quite tricky. I tried starting with the dynamical equation:
$$ ma=m\frac{dv}{dt}=-\beta v$$which we can rearrange to get
$$ \frac{dv}{v}=-\frac{\beta}{m}dt$$We can integrate this:
$$ \int_{v}^{\alpha v}\frac{dv}{v}=-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\beta}{m}dt$$However, the answer is dependent of time. I also tried writing
$$ ma=m\frac{dv}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dx}v$$
and the dynamical equation becomes:
$$ m\frac{dv}{dx}=-\beta$$
we can rearrange this:
$$ mdv=-\beta dx$$
but again, after integrating, the answer is dependent in turn on the distance the object traversed.

Any hints?

Comment: The velocity will get any value in $(0,v]$. This problem can't be solved.

Comment: OMG. I didn't see "After traversing distance l" ! And yes. It can be easily solved. Sorry for giving uneducated comment.

Comment: The question was edited by the OP  to replace "after an unknown time" to "after traversing a distance $l$. The new problem can  be solved, the old one cannot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your equation is is $v(t)=v(0) \exp\{-\beta t/m\}$ as may be verified by plugging it in.

Comment: Aaaand? It's dependent on time.  The task is to express $\beta$ as a function of $v$ and $\alpha$ only.

Comment: There is no solution to your original problem. You have not been given enough data.

Comment: @Mermon In the part you quoted of the question it doesn't specify that it needs to be a function of only $v $ and $\alpha $.  Are you sure you can't have $t $ in the answer?  This question is about a transient response, without using time we can really solve it.

Comment: Well, and if we add that the body traversed distance $l$?

Comment: NMevermind, solved it.